# disable and remove pjax functionality fom limesurvey

Tags: yii, pjax, limesurvey

is it possible to remove pjax functionality from limesurvey? it caused a lot of problems for me, I just want the page load normally

Answer (score 0):

For public part : no pjax on last version (since 3.X if i don't make error).